# Internal struggles: Which answer to accept?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, upvotes

I sometimes find myself having troubles with accepting an answer because I simply do not know on which criteria to accept the best answer.

When I ask a question about a problem there are multiple way to solve it for instance:

1. You can help the user to find the answer themselves by providing hints or references to useful material.
2. You can give the answer the way the user is trying to find it, for instance you are trying something with lists, the person answers with an implementation using lists
3. You can give the answer to the question with a totally different but supreme implementation of a solution to the same problem.

It often happens that different people answer and their answer belong to these different categories and all of their answers helped me in different ways. While I can make a case one is better within one of these catagories I can not say that one is better between categories.

Comment: That is what the coin on my desk is for, though, if you are a pair-programmer, you could try rock/paper/scissors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would accept the answer that helped you "the most", regardless of what category it falls in; I don't think any of the categories you mentioned are necessarily "better" than the others. What qualifies it as being the most helpful to you can be a bit subjective, but it should either answer or lead you to the answer of the question asked.

Comment: I am still thinking about which answer to accept now.

Comment: I think [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276602/internal-struggles-which-answer-to-accept) might be of assistance :)

Answer (score 3):

When accepting an answer, follow these simple guidelines outlined in [How to update and accept answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251078/3920237):

Source: [gnat](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251399/3920237), <sub>note this actually comes from the MSE FAQ [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)</sub>

> #### Which answer should I choose?
>
> - Don't hesitate to accept an answer that is well-written, suggests a good practice and works for you.
> - Otherwise, even if there are answers that are *good enough* but that you're not entirely satisfied by, you might wait 24 to 48 hours to
>   give other people a chance to give you a better answer. A question
>   with an accepted answer isn't as likely to receive further attention
>   as one without an accepted answer.
> - Make sure that besides working for you, the answer is really good practice. Sometimes after the answer gets accepted, another comes in,
>   uncovering the fact that previous one was in fact a bad hack.
> - **The bottom line is that you should accept the answer that you found to be the most helpful to you, personally.**

Comment: Abhorr cargo-culting. Be aware that "good practice" is context-dependent, and being popular neither makes it good, nor makes it apply in your case. Good advice comes with a rationale.

Comment: OP wrote "I can not say that one is better between categories."  S/he doesn't know which is the most helpful, ... personally.  @MartinJames' comment seems more useful.  (However: A coin?  No, code up a decision-making program.  Maybe download a random number generator first, if your language doesn't have a good one built in.  Better yet, write your own RNG.  Or research RNG algorithms and create the best one yet.  That stuff is easy, right?)