# How can I toggle the answer check mark from a different account?

Tags: support, answers, accounts

I marked one of my questions as answered by toggling the checkmark next to the response from greyed out to filled in.  Now I wish to toggle the checkmark off because I do not think the question was completely answered, and I'd like to learn more.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers/251399#251399) indicate that I should simply be able to "change which answer is accepted, or simply un-accept the answer, at any time" -- presumably by a click which toggles the checkmark off?  But I'm clickin'! And no toggle!

I am logged in while looking at the question/answer via my profile.  What could the issue be?

Comment: original question/answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61001865/is-it-possible-to-display-data-from-seatgeek-api-call-on-my-squarespace-site.  I am on chrome.  No errors related to checkmark seen in console when clicking checkmark.

Comment: That question is not yours, at least not linked to the account you asked this meta question  with.

Comment: rene - what is the username you see for the account that asked the original question in Stack Overflow?  What is the account you see now on Meta Stack Overflow? Currently on my view I see username as elderlyman in all locations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are now user [7134342](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7134342/elderlyman).

The question you try remove the accepted answer from belongs to user [12506946](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12506946/elderlyman).

For obvious reasons you can't unaccept answers on questions from other users.

(usernames don't have to be unique on SO. The same username doesn't mean it is the same user)

Try to [merge your accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous) and once you completed that you should be able to unaccept that answer.

Comment: thanks rene - toggled the checkmark a couple times here to be sure!  now to kill this account...